# Batch: Redirecting FC output, parsing, and claim variables

Tags: batch-file, file-comparison

I am attempting to use FC to compare files but would like to take the output of the FC command, parse it out, and claim variables to copy the source file over the remote file that does not match, syncing essentially.

My code is really simple because `fc` does everything I need:

```
 @echo off

set source=C:\source\
set remote=C:\remote\

fc /b %source%\*.* %remote%\*.*
```

Example of fc output if file is different:

```
00000000 47 55
00000001 44 48
00000002 55 61
FC: C:\source\test.txt longer than C:\remote\test.txt
```

The last line is what I want and I'd like to parse out with the file paths and use them to claim variables to use in

```
xcopy %sourcefile% %remotefile%
```

This will need to have the ability to parse multiple fc file outputs.

Comment: You know if the compared files are different but of same size there will not be such last line, so do you want to synchronise only files that changed in length? and what if a source file is shorter than the respective remote file? the last line will be reversed then (it always says "longer than", there is no "shorter than")...

Comment: There are other possibilities to synchronise: [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) can be used to copy only newer files (`/D`) and only already existing ones (`/U`), or only those with the archive attribute set (`/M`) (the system sets this as soon as a file is edited); [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) establishes advanced synchronisation options...

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I wasn't aware that the output of FC would reverse if the source is shorter. FC can also compare based of the binary, ASCII, and/or Unicode; but that's if it can open & read it.  I will look further in to xcopy & robocopy to see if those are avenues of possibility. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[`FC.EXE` will set an ErrorLevel as follows](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html):

> ```
> -1 Invalid syntax (e.g. only one file passed) 
> 0 The files are identical.
> 1 The files are different.
> 2 Cannot find at least one of the files.
> ```

Your script could be (with some debugging `echo`s and `copy` command commented up by `REM`).

```
@echo off

set "source=C:\source"
set "remote=C:\remote"

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B "%source%\" /A:-D') do (
  >NUL 2>&1 FC /b "%source%\%%~G" "%remote%\%%~G"
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo %%G files differ or remote does not exist
    REM copy /B /Y "%source%\%%~G" "%remote%\%%~G"
  ) else (
    echo %%G files match
  )
)
```

However, [`ROBOCOPY.exe` - Robust File and Folder Copy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) offers more advanced options including recurse into subfolders.

If you can't use `ROBOCOPY` for any reason, then above script changes as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

set "sourceMain=C:\source"
set "remoteMain=C:\remote"

call :subFolder "%sourceMain%" "%remoteMain%" "%sourceMain%"

rem traverse source subfolder structure
for /F "delims=" %%g in ('dir /B /S "%source%\" /A:D 2^>NUL') do (
  call :subFolder "%sourceMain%" "%remoteMain%" "%%~g"
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:subFolder
    rem adapted original script 
set "sourceRoot=%~1"
set "remoteRoot=%~2"

set "source=%~3"
call set "remote=%%source:%sourceRoot%=%remoteRoot%%%"     compute target folder

ECHO *** comparing "%source%" vs. "%remote%" ***
rem next command creates target folder if it does not exists yet
MD "%remote%" 2>NUL

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B "%source%\" /A:-D 2^>NUL') do (
  >NUL 2>&1 FC /b "%source%\%%~G" "%remote%\%%~G"
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo %%G files differ or remote does not exist
    REM copy /B /Y "%source%\%%~G" "%remote%\%%~G"
  ) else (
    echo %%G files match
  )
)
goto :eof
```

Note that target folder computation by [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) is moved from `%%g` loop body into `:subFolder` subroutine for handy reasons: no need to activate [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). 

Note that `%%G` loop keeps unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks to **ashipfl** and **JosefZ** I found that ROBOCOPY was exactly what I needed. SS64.com had an example that was perfect for me to work from; code is below along with a link to its ROBOCOPY page:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET _source=\\FileServ1\e$\users

SET _dest=\\FileServ2\e$\BackupUsers

SET _what=/COPYALL /B /MIR
:: /COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info
:: /B :: copy files in Backup mode. 
:: /MIR :: MIRror a directory tree 

SET _options=/R:0 /W:0 /LOG:C:\batch\RoboLog.txt /NFL /NDL
:: /R:n :: number of Retries
:: /W:n :: Wait time between retries
:: /LOG :: Output log file
:: /NFL :: No file logging
:: /NDL :: No dir logging

ROBOCOPY %_source% %_dest% %_what% %_options%
```

http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html